# AngularJS-MVVM-Problem with binding the view and the model (scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm, angularjs-scope, model-binding

I didn't understand where is the problem, I'm studying a new course in Coursera I'd copied the same code, but it seems that the scope doesn't work! Can u please help me? Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7mc7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
<html ng-app="myFirstApp">
```

I recommend you to see the console, because it gives us a lot of information in case a problem occurs as in this case:

```
Failed to instantiate module myFirstApp due to: Module 'myFirstApp' is not available!
```

Then it eliminates

```
ng-app="myFirstApp"
```

I also recommend placing the code here and not on images